# Error al convertir objeto DBNull datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente código:

Esta declarada la variable al principio de todo mi código:

```
int editado = 0;
```

Este metodo lo utilizo en un boton.

```
public void Insertar
                   { try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvFormulacion.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Program.con.Close();
                Program.con.Open();

                cm = new SqlCommand("insert into Formulacion values(@NombreConcepto,@cantidad,@precio,@editado", Program.con);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreConcepto", dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["MateriaPrima"].Value);

                if (dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["PrecioUnitario"].Value == null)
                {
                    dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["PrecioUnitario"].Value = "0";
                }
                if (dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Cant"].Value == null)
                {
                    dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Cant"].Value = "0";
                }

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Editar"].Value) == true)//////Linea de error DBnull
                {
                    editado = 1;
                }
                else if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Editar"].Value) == false)
                {
                    editado = 0;
                }                   
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@editado", editado);

                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio", dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["PrecioUnitario"].Value);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Cant"].Value);

                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cm.Dispose();
                Program.con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Cuando intento registrar ese campo en la base de datos me muestra el error

> Error al convertir DBNull

Este error a veces me aparece y a veces no... Como lo puedo corregir.
Esta es la exception:

```
Excepción producida: "System.InvalidCastException" en mscorlib.dll ("No se puede convertir un objeto DBNull en otros tipos.")   System.InvalidCastException
```

Comment: Coloca todo el código, en especial desde la declaración de la variable editado. Saludos

Comment: ¿Has utilizado las herramientas de depuración de Visual Studio para depurar tu código y ver exactamente qué valor contiene tu código? Coloca breakpoints antes del error, inspecciona las propiedades a ver si realmente contiene un valor de tipo bool. A veces, una buena depuración ayuda.

Comment: Por que sabes que ese campo y no otro el que te está dando el error? Sería interesante que nos pegaras entero el texto de la excepción que te da

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor que tiene `dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Editar"].Value` cuando te envía la excepción es nulo y por eso te falla el código al momento de hacer la conversión a booleano.

Puedes validar si es nulo usando: `Convert.IsDBNull()`

Suponiendo que si el valor en `dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Editar"].Value` es nulo se puede tomar como falso:

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull (dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Editar"].Value)== true) // el valor en Editar es null
        {
            editado = 0;
        }
else {
    if (Convert.ToBoolean (dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Editar"].Value) == true)
    {
        editado = 1;
    }
    else if (Convert.ToBoolean (dgvFormulacion.Rows[i].Cells["Editar"].Value) == false)
    {
        editado = 0;
    }
}
```

La otra opción es que validez como se llena `dgvFormulacion` para que cuando se ejecute el metodo `insertar` siempre tenga un valor. Para esto puedes depurar tu codigo en el Visual Studio como ya te comentaron.